# How can I receive a key press from keyboard in assembly (8086 emu)?

Tags: assembly

How can I receive a **key press** from keyboard in **assembly** (8086 emu)? ..such that 
when some specific key is pressed, then some action need be taken (an action like adding 2 numbers or sth like that)...

For example, let's say I have the value **2** stored in **AX** ,the value **3** in **BX** , and while running the code, if I pressed **"+"** for example, then **Add** **AX** **and BX**, and if I pressed **"-"** then **subtract AX from BX**, otherwise don't do anything..

Can anyone explain the code to do that in details? I'm a complete newbie to Assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked 2 Questions in a Single Question: 
 **1. Getting Values From Keyboard**

```
 MOV AH,01h
 INT 21H
```

The entered number will be stored in DL general purpose register in ASCII Form.

Example: 
You entered 'A' that has an ASCII value of 65 the DL will contain a value of 01000001. 
To learn more about ASCII value I'd like to suggest you [ASCII Table](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html)

**2. Performing Operations based on Input**:
You can perform various operations simply by comparing the value of DL register with ASCII values.
Example:

```
    CMP DL, 43 ; '+' has ASCII value of 43 
    JE addition;
     <<Some code here>>
     <<Some code here>>
     <<Some code here>>
ADDITION:
     ADD AX , BX
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was really clear and helpful.